# Putty becomes slow

Tags: windows-10, putty

On Windows 10 I am using Putty to log in to Linux machines.

The problem seems to occur with all releases of Putty.

After about 3 minutes the connection becomes slow and editing files becomes a very slow process.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you also connect to hosts on your local network? Does the problem occur there as well? Have you tried using the OpenSSH client in WSL? Or using Git Bash? I suspect the problem lies with your internet connection. What kind of connection is it, DSL/Cable/3G/…? What make and model is your router and modem (if any)?

Comment: Before starting the connection go to "Connection" in the options tree and set the value "Seconds between keepalives" to for example 10. Just to make sure no involved network  component thinks that the connection is stalled if you don't use it every second.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question intending to answer it myself but when I started putting together the evidence I discovered that the problem had gone away in the latest update. Microsoft Windows 10 Pro                               OS Version: 10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041

The problem *occurred* because Windows 10 tried to autotune the connection.

The fix *was* to do this using Command Prompt (cmd.exe).

```
netsh int tcp show global
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
```

This needed to be done just once.

This does not seem to have any impact on web browsers but I guess there might be situations where it does.

Does anybody want to suggest a way to disable autotuning just for putty connections?